# Fastlane error in android apk build 'increment_version_code'

Tags: android, android-studio, fastlane, fastlane-deliver, fastlane-match

I am getting the errors in the fastlane for building a signed apk as an assembleRelease apk and i want to deploy the update on the playstore but when i firing the fastlane command at the time i am getting the error for the **increment_version_code**.

```
Shubhams-MacBook-Air:ProjectPath shubhamsejpal$ fastlane beta
[✔]  
[23:33:51]: fastlane detected a Gemfile in the current directory
[23:33:51]: however it seems like you don't use `bundle exec`
[23:33:51]: to launch fastlane faster, please use
[23:33:51]: 
[23:33:51]: $ bundle exec fastlane beta
[23:33:51]: 
[23:33:51]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
[23:33:51]: WARNING: fastlane requires your locale to be set to UTF-8. To learn more go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#set-up-environment-variables
[23:33:52]: ----------------------------------------
[23:33:52]: --- Step: Verifying fastlane version ---
[23:33:52]: ----------------------------------------
[23:33:52]: Your fastlane version 2.90.0 matches the minimum requirement of 2.64.0  ✅
[23:33:52]: ------------------------------
[23:33:52]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[23:33:52]: ------------------------------
[23:33:52]: Driving the lane 'android beta' 
+------------------+--------------+
|          Lane Context           |
+------------------+--------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | android      |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | android      |
| LANE_NAME        | android beta |
+------------------+--------------+
[23:33:52]: Could not find action, lane or variable 'increment_version_code'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions

+------+---------------------+-------------+
|             fastlane summary             |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action              | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying fastlane  | 0           |
|      | version             |             |
| 2    | default_platform    | 0           |
+------+---------------------+-------------+

[23:33:52]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Could not find action, lane or variable 'increment_version_code'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
[23:33:52]: WARNING: fastlane requires your locale to be set to UTF-8. To learn more go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#set-up-environment-variables
```

Answer (score 12):

you have to add this plugin

`fastlane add_plugin increment_version_code`

[reference url](https://github.com/Jems22/fastlane-plugin-increment_version_code)

Comment: after adding the plugin its giving ```[!] Impossible to find the version code with the specified properties ```

Comment: Same here, "Impossible to find the version code with the specified properties".

Comment: Make sure to run the increment action first before the build action in the lane. the order matters. if you have already build the aab or apk, rebuild it again.